# default values in LINQ query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have following Linq query/function in my MVC3 application.

```
public AuditTrail GetNamesAddressesEmployers(long registryId , int changedField) {
    var otherNameAndAddress = (from a in context.AuditTrails
                               where a.ChangedField == changedField
                                  && a.RegistryId == registryId
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();
    return otherNameAndAddress;   
}
```

I want that if otherNameAndAddress = null then its properties should be assigned some values.

otherNameAndAddress has Name and description property. This GetNamesAddressesEmployers is being used at 3 places. I want to assign different values to name and description when otherNameAndAddress  = null at all three locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using FirstOrDefault() so why not specify the Default:

```
public AuditTrail GetNamesAddressesEmployers(long registryId, int changedField)
{
    return context.AuditTrails            
        .Where(a => a.ChangedField == changedField 
             && a.RegistryId == registryId)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new AuditTrail { /* fill properties here */ })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I think you wanted to put the DefaultIfEmpty call *after* the Where, didn't you? That in itself indicates a potential reason not to use this method - it's clearly error-prone :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could change the return statement to:

```
return otherNameAndAddress ?? new AuditTrail { Name = "Default",
                                               Description = "Default };
```

or something like that... but you say you want to assign *different* default values for different calls. That means you'll either need to pass the default in, or perform the defaulting (e.g. in the same way, via the null-coalescing operator) at the call site.

For example:

```
public AuditTrail GetNamesAddressesEmployers(long registryId, int changedField,
                                             AuditField defaultValue) {
    var otherNameAndAddress = (from a in context.AuditTrails
                               where a.ChangedField == changedField
                                  && a.RegistryId == registryId
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();
    return otherNameAndAddress && defaultValue; 
}
```

*or* keep it as it currently is, and use this at the call site:

```
var auditTrail = GetNamesAddressesEmployers(registryId, changedField) ??
                 new AuditTrail { Name = "Foo", Description = "Bar" };
```

It's not really clear which is best based on your description.

EDIT: As mentioned by Justin, you could use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) instead (just before `FirstOrDefault`). That means you *have* to pass the value in rather than doing it at the call site, but other than that they're very similar solutions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you go this route over specifying a default using DefaultIfEmpty and then simply letting FirstOrDefault do its job? I've used both in the past and either way always stirs a discussion with my co-workers.

Comment: @Justin: I always forget about DefaultIfEmpty allowing a value to be specified. It's a shame that FirstOrDefault doesn't. Still, I think it's not much clearer either way, to be honest.

Comment: @Jon - I'd certainly agree. Passing the default value as a parameter to FirstOrDefault would certainly make the most sense to me.

Comment: @Justin: I suppose there's nothing to stop you from adding your own extension method which just returns `DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue).FirstOrDefault()` :)

Comment: @jon I want different default values assigned so I tried using your second solution but I am getting error: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'myproj.Models.AuditTrail' and 'myproj.Models.AuditTrail'

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Sorry, that && should have been a ??. Fixed in the answer now.